# application reporting

Tags: report

1. I am just wondering, should i build the reporting engine inside my web application or I should use a third party tool that users will login to and access reports? what is the best case.
2. Which java reporting tools do you guys use and for what reason? I am familiar with jasper and I have used it but its on GPL license so I dont intend to use it in an close project.
   I am exploring ART art.sourceforge.net .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have integrated report viewer into my applications, I find it best to reduce number of interfaces for the users.

2. As I'm familiar with Crystal Reports, I'd use Crystal for java

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Stimulsoft Reports.Fx for Java. It is not free or open source code but a very good one.

Answer (score 0):

Check Valentina Reports: http://valentina-db.com/en/valentina-reports-adk-overview

- C++ based, fast, powerful cross-platform: mac/win/linux.
- Can use as data source MS SQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, ValentinaDB.
- Can be used as embedded report engine to integrate into your app made on C/C++, C#, .NET, COM, Obj-C, Java, PHP, Xojo, ...
- Can be integrated into your app as VCLIENT to Valentina Report Server
- Have powerful GUI Report Editor in Valentina Studio application (3 OS).

Valentina Report Server is free for 5 connections. Compare to price of Crystal Reports. Top price of Report Server unlimited is only 1500$.

If you want to use local embedded report enginem, then price go 199$ per 1 OS, 399$ for 3 OS bundle.